# Rotating transformation points

Tags: c, math, rotation, transformation, image-rotation

In a variety of editors such as Power Point we can often see transformation points like these:

[image]

and I have an implementation for those. When which point is clicked is detected, the mouse position is stored as `xClick` and `yClick`. When cursor is moved we have `xPos` and `yPos`. To get the value(s) of how much the image should stretch, I simply do this: `h = xPos - xClick` and `v = yPos - yClick` and then use this matrix:

```
{
    {0, 0}, /* pad */
    {h, v},
    {0, v},
    {-h, v},
    {h, 0},
    {0, 0}, /* pad */
    {-h, 0},
    {h, -v},
    {0, -v},
    {-h, -v}
}
```

as a lookup table to feed it to a function that accepts those values `h` and `v` and performs the stretching accordingly. The problem is when the image is rotated to an arbitrary angle. For example:

[image]

Now point 2 should be treated as the previous 4 (i.e `{h, 0}`) but it will be treated like this instead: `{0, v}` which means the image will stretch vertically when the cursor goes higher instead of horizontally when the cursor goes to the left. I really don't have any clue on what to do from here. I've tried to rotate `h` and `v` in many ways but that was just another pitiful blindfolded trial and error attempt.

What should I do to rotate the transformation points properly?
(note that the positions of the transformation points are rotated properly, hence it detects which point is clicked already, but not how the stretch values are interpolated)

Comment: You have to transform the mouse coordinates into the GUI element local coordinates and use that for your editation... Beware any change in GUI element coordinate system result in change of old mouse position values too so you need to re transform them again to compensate otherwise it will screw the next editation iteration.